# jquery if data not empty add class issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

not sure why this isn't working still fairly new with js. I am trying to check if there is any data and if there is then it should add a hidden class or should remove it if it has no data.

```
 $(function() {

    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var followerList=$("#followerlist");
        if($('#search').val() !== ""){
            followerList.addClass('hidden');
        }else{
            followerList.removeClass('hidden');
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/search/",
            data: {
                'search_text': $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    });
});



function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

Comment: Find a good syntax linting tool. Either in an IDE (code editor) or an online one. Your code has numerous syntax issues. Also look for syntax errors thrown  in browser console....it will tell you what line they are on also...the first one anyway

Comment: thanks I was using the console and tried to go from it. I am using sublime text currently but going to use an IDE for it soon. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Sublime will lint, just need to use it

Comment: Thanks found it in there now should help me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **searchSuccess** function has to be like this:

```
function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
        var followerList=$(".followerlist");
        $('#search-results').html(data);
        if(data !== "")
        {
                followerList.addClass("hidden");
        }
        else
        {
                followerList.removeClass("hidden");
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works but I cannot remove the hidden class on an else statement. is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I have tried this and still will not remove the class.

Comment: Can you inspect the element and debug ?

Comment: updated the code got it working by moving the if else statement to the keyup function and works perfectly now thanks for your help.